# Using subclass' method in superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, subclass, superclass

I have a class (called SubClass for simplicity) that extends SuperClass and implements IClass.
I know that you can call SuperClass' methods by using super.method(), but is it possible to call a method from SubClass which it implements from IClass?

Example:

```
public class SuperClass {

    public void method(){

        implementedMethod();

    }

}
```

Subclass:

```
public class SubClass extends SuperClass implements IClass{

    public void implementedMethod() {

        System.out.println("Hello World");

    }

}
```

IClass:

```
public interface IClass {

    public void implementedMethod();

}
```

I would like to call SubClass' implementedMethod() (Which it gets from IClass) from SuperClass

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: You likely have a design issue in your is-a relationship if you need to call a subclass method from the superclass.

Comment: i don't get your issue, what you want to achieve? if you have something of abstract SuperClass Type you want to chose what subclass would execute?

Comment: What's the use case? Why would you ever want to call a subclass's method from a superclass without that method being abstract and therefore guaranteed to exist in a subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the types above, `anExpressionOfTypeSubClassOrIClass.implementedMethod()` must be used. Note that the *Type of an expression* - the *view* it provides - must have the method intended to be used. In this case, an expression of type SuperClass cannot be used here because it has no declared `implementedMethod` member.

One approach - and arguably the preferred approach - is to use [abstract methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html). Even though abstract methods are not strictly required for [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) they describe scenarios such as this where a subclass should provide the implementation. (The abstract methods could be replaced with empty method *expecting* - but not requiring - to be overridden in sublcasses, but why not use `abstract` for its designed purpose?)

```
abstract class SuperClass implements IClass {
    // Don't implement this, but declare it abstract
    // so that we can conform to IClass as well
    public abstract void implementedMethod();

    public void method () {
       // Now this object (which conforms to IClass) has implementedMethod
       // which will be implemented by a concrete subclass.
       implementedMethod();
    }
}
```

This has the "negative" aspects that SuperClass cannot be directly instantiated (it is abstract, after all) and that SuperClass must implement (or, as shown, delegate out via abstract) the expected signature. In this case I also chose to make SuperClass implement IClass even though it's not strictly required because it guarantees that the SuperClass and all subclasses can be *viewed* as an IClass.

Alternatively, remember that *Types of Expressions are just views* of objects and are not necessarily the same as the actual *Concrete Type* of object. While I would advise against using the following code because it *loses some type-safety*, I think it shows the important point.

```
class SuperClass {
    public void method () {
        // We try to cast and NARROW the type to a
        // specific "view". This can fail which is one
        // reason why it's not usually appropriate.
        ((IClass)this).implementedMethod();
    }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass implements IClass {
  // ..
}

class BrokenSubClass extends SuperClass () {
}

// OK! Although it is the SAME OBJECT, the SuperClass
// method can "view" the current instance (this) as an IClass
// because SubClass implements IClass. This view must be
// explicitly request through a cast because SuperClass itself
// does not implement IClass or have a suitable method to override.
(new SubClass()).method();

// BAD! ClassCastException, BrokenSubClass cannot be "viewed" as IClass!
// But we didn't know until runtime due to lost type-safety.
(new BrokenSubClass()).method();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make the super class abstract:

```
public abstract class SuperClass implements IClass {
    public void method(){
        implementedMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: @tbodt Why not? It seems to be exactly what he is trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to call that method would be to create an object of type SubClass (in SuperClass) and call subClassInstance.implementedMethod().

I also want to stress that this is very inelegant. As stated in a comment on your question, you should reconsider your class designs if your superclass needs to call a subclass method.

Comment: A new SubClass instance *doesn't* need to be created inside SuperClass. Although generally inadvisable, this would "work": `class SuperClass { void ick() { ((IClass)this).implementedMethod(); } .. } .. new SubClass().ick()`. In this case, although the method `ick` (defined in the SuperClass, but called on an instance of a SubClass) requires that the current instance conform to the particular Type (IClass here) or the cast will fail.

Comment: (Note that in my previous comment/example there is *no* object of type SubClass "created .. in SuperClass". The actual type of an object and the type of an expression which is a *view* of said object can differ.)